# Subtraction and Intersection of two vectors of pointers in C++

Tags: c++, stdvector

I've two vectors having pointers to my custom class object.
The pointers in these two vectors don't point to the same object, but the values stored in the objects are same.

My custom class structure is:

```
Class Item
{
   string ItemId;
   string ItemDescription;
   float ItemPrice;
}
```

The first vector(**V1**) is having *n* entries and the second vector(**V2**) is having *m* entries *(n>m)*.

I've to perform two operations:

Get a vector which has common objects in both **V1** and **V2**. *By common, I mean to say that the ItemId for the elements is same.* (Can be referred as ***Intersection of V1 and V2***).

Get a vector which has the elements which are not present in **V2**. (Can be referred as ***V1-V2***).

**How to do this in an efficient manner??**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is example of how to do it using STL set_intersection and set_difference to get what you wanted:

```
class Item
{
public:
    Item(int i):ItemId(i){}

   int ItemId;
   string ItemDescription;
   float ItemPrice;

   bool operator<(const Item& rhs)
   {
       return ItemId < rhs.ItemId;
   }
   bool operator==(const Item& rhs)
   {
       return ItemId == rhs.ItemId;
   }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Item> myvec1;
    myvec1.push_back(Item(1));
    myvec1.push_back(Item(2));
    myvec1.push_back(Item(1));
    myvec1.push_back(Item(10));
    myvec1.push_back(Item(5));
    myvec1.push_back(Item(3));
    myvec1.push_back(Item(10));


    std::vector<Item> myvec2;
    myvec2.push_back(Item(10));
    myvec2.push_back(Item(1));
    myvec2.push_back(Item(10));
    myvec2.push_back(Item(1));
    myvec2.push_back(Item(3));

    std::sort(myvec1.begin(), myvec1.end());
    std::sort(myvec2.begin(), myvec2.end());

    myvec1.erase(std::unique(myvec1.begin(), myvec1.end()), myvec1.end());
    myvec2.erase(std::unique(myvec2.begin(), myvec2.end()), myvec2.end());

    std::vector<Item> myvec3; //Intersection of V1 and V2
    std::vector<Item> myvec4; //V1-V2
    set_intersection(myvec1.begin(),myvec1.end(), myvec2.begin(),myvec2.end(), std::back_inserter(myvec3)); //myvec3: 1 3 10
    set_difference(myvec1.begin(),myvec1.end(), myvec2.begin(),myvec2.end(), std::back_inserter(myvec4));   //myvec4: 2 5 
}
```

Comment: It works fine when i've objects in vector, but when the vectors have pointers to objects, it doesn't works.

Comment: It shouldn't make much different if you store pointer in vector, but you might want to considering using smart pointer with vector like boost::shared_ptr so you don't need to worry about memory management.

Comment: @Amresh: you need to provide the ordering to `sort`, `set_intersection` and `set_difference`. Write a function (or functor) that takes two `Item*` parameters and returns `true` if the first one's ID is less than the second one's ID, otherwise `false`.

Comment: @Amresh, I have added another answer for using pointer (using smart pointer, see below

Answer (score 1):

If you are using stl, for first problem you can use [set_intersection](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set_intersection.html), for second [set_difference](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set_difference.html)

Comment: But how to do that for my custom class. Any examples or link will be helpful.

Comment: last param it's a comparison function. You can implement that function as you need. You can find an example in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/. Just modify function to receive const Item& as param

Comment: Alternatively you could simply implement `bool operator<(const Item & other) const { return ItemId < other.ItemId; }`, and you can use your `Item`s in a set.

Comment: Don't forget sort those two vectors first in ascending order according to operator< of class Item as set_intersection and set_different require that

Answer (score 1):

@Amresh, this is the example you wanted using vector with pointer. But I have used boost::shared_ptr instead of raw pointer so you need to worry about memory management:

```
class Item;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Item> MyPtr;
typedef std::vector<MyPtr> VecType;

class Item
{
public:
    Item(int i):ItemId(i){}
    friend bool operator<(MyPtr lhs, MyPtr rhs);
    friend bool operator==(MyPtr lhs, MyPtr rhs);

   int ItemId;
   string ItemDescription;
   float ItemPrice;

   bool operator<(const Item& rhs)
   {
       return ItemId < rhs.ItemId;
   }
   bool operator==(const Item& rhs)
   {
       return ItemId == rhs.ItemId;
   }
};



bool operator<(MyPtr lhs, MyPtr rhs)
{
    return lhs->ItemId < rhs->ItemId ;
}

bool operator==(MyPtr lhs, MyPtr rhs)
{
    return lhs->ItemId == rhs->ItemId ;
}

int main()
{

    VecType myvec1;
    myvec1.push_back(MyPtr(new Item(2)));
    myvec1.push_back(MyPtr(new Item(1)));
    myvec1.push_back(MyPtr(new Item(10)));
    myvec1.push_back(MyPtr(new Item(5)));
    myvec1.push_back(MyPtr(new Item(3)));
    myvec1.push_back(MyPtr(new Item(10)));

    VecType myvec2;
    myvec2.push_back(MyPtr(new Item(10)));
    myvec2.push_back(MyPtr(new Item(1)));
    myvec2.push_back(MyPtr(new Item(10)));
    myvec2.push_back(MyPtr(new Item(1)));
    myvec2.push_back(MyPtr(new Item(3)));

    std::sort(myvec1.begin(), myvec1.end());
    std::sort(myvec2.begin(), myvec2.end());

    myvec1.erase(std::unique(myvec1.begin(), myvec1.end()), myvec1.end());
    myvec2.erase(std::unique(myvec2.begin(), myvec2.end()), myvec2.end());

    VecType myvec3; //Intersection of V1 and V2
    VecType myvec4; //V1-V2
    set_intersection(myvec1.begin(),myvec1.end(), myvec2.begin(),myvec2.end(), std::back_inserter(myvec3)); //myvec3: 1 3 10
    set_difference(myvec1.begin(),myvec1.end(), myvec2.begin(),myvec2.end(), std::back_inserter(myvec4));   //myvec4: 2 5 
}
```